# entity framework: how to log the size of retrieved data?

Tags: entity-framework-6, entity-framework-6.1

Since under the EF6 context object, the stream readers do all work may be the EF6 track the size of data that was read for the current context object and there is possibility to get this number for logging purposes (e.g. as performance counter)?

I have read that ADO by itself provide the reach counters system. Is it possible to use it together with EF6 for prophylactic purposes in production environment? Something like adding to the log "warning! too much data retrieved".

It seems it can be done using IDbCommandInterceptor. But I'm not sure that I want to write many lines of code to achive the ruslt I need...

Comment: I think this is a good question, but maybe you should explain what exactly you mean by the "reach counters system". Maybe the new interception framework in EF 6.1 can be used here.

Comment: Thank you. I mean reach "performance" counters.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254503%28v=vs.110%29.aspx Unfortunately it is not so reach: there are no "size" counters for "bytes read/write".